# What is necessary to feel another Force sensitive being?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force

There have been different questions on why the Jedi did not feel that Palpatine was a Sith, e.g. [Why couldn't the Jedi detect Senator Palpatine as having powers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13849/why-couldnt-the-jedi-detect-senator-palpatine-as-having-powers) and the answer was that Palpatine had to mask it:

> Palpatine was using [Force Stealth](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_stealth) to hide his Force presence from the Jedi.

However, with Anakin, Qui-Gon and Obi-Wan needed Anakin to tell about his podracing abilities to be recognized to be Force sensitive:

So, can only trained Force users be recognized by other Force sensitive beings, do they have to use the Force actively in order to be recognized or how does this exactly work?

Answer as canon, if possible. If no canon answer exists, a Legends explanation is also accepted.